# How to wait for all superagent calls to complete before reaching the end of the function

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax, superagent

I am trying to make multiple api calls which are dynamically created from some input, the issue is that the method ends prior to the completion of all Ajax calls. I need to trigger an additional function to use the resulting json values from the Api calls following all results being achieved.

I am pretty sure, I am probably using promises incorrectly, or getting confused on them most certainly, I am still trying to get the hang of them, but can't get my head around this issue. All help greatly appreciated.

The **fields()** function should return an array of objects containing similar to the below 2 objects.

```
{"title":"Businessunit",
 "content":
    {"filter":
        {
            "fields":{"businessunitid":true,"settingsid":true,"archived":true}
        }
    }
}

{"title":"Address",
 "content":
    {"filter":
        {
            "fields":{"addressid":true}
        }
    }
}
```

```
function Export()
{
        queryGroup = fields();

        const response = async.map(queryGroup, a=>ApiCall(a), 

                    function(err, results) {
                        return results;
                    });
        return response;

}

async function ApiCall(lookup)
{
    console.log("LOOKUP: " + JSON.stringify(lookup));
    var table = new Object();

        superagent
        .get(document.getElementById("ApiEndPoint").value+'/api/'+document.getElementById("ApiKey").value+'/'+lookup.title)
        .query(lookup.content)
        .set('accept', 'json')
        .then(res => 
        { 
            table["Body"] = res.body
            table["Name"] = lookup.title;

            console.log("completed: "+ lookup.title);

            return table;
        }).then(table => {return Promise.resolve(table);});

}
```

Comment: Is `queryGroup` an array, which has elements of `lookup`?

Comment: Hi @Certainperformance, that is correct. Apologies for not including in my example, I will update my code to include this. Was a bit of a sleepy post zzz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Export` should return a `Promise.all` once all `apiCall`s are processed. Create the object to be returned inside the last `.then` in `apiCall`, so that the Promise chain resolves to that object.

Because `export` is a reserved keyword, it would probably be a good idea to use a different name for that function, like `getAllFieldInfo` or something of the sort:

```
function getAllFieldInfo() {
  return Promise.all(fields().map(apiCall));
}

function apiCall(lookup) {
  const superagentGetParam = document.getElementById("ApiEndPoint").value + '/api/' + document.getElementById("ApiKey").value + '/' + lookup.title;
  return superagent
    .get(superagentGetParam)
    .query(lookup.content)
    .set('accept', 'json')
    .then(res => ({
      Body: res.body,
      Name: lookup.title
    }));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance, that worked exactly as I wanted. You have untangled my mess. I have been reworking these parts for weeks, trying to get the hang of it, If I could give you more kudos, I would! :) One very happy camper. Thanks again